# How can I simplify the code for multiple nested if else statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coffeescript

I am currently using the following code for comparison but as you can see, I am making tonnes of if else statements. Is there a way to simplify the code and make it more efficient?

```
getGenderRef: (grammer=nil) ->
  @gender_ref = ""
  gender = this.get('gender')
  if gender? and gender == 'male'
    if grammer == 'he'
      @gender_ref = 'he'
    else if grammer == 'his'
      @gender_ref == 'his'
    else if grammer == 'him'
      @gender_ref == 'him'
  else if gender? and gender == 'female'
    if grammer == 'he'
      @gender_ref = 'she'
    else if grammer == 'his'
      @gender_ref == 'her'
    else if grammer == 'him'
      @gender_ref == 'her'
  else if gender? or gender == null
    if grammer == 'he'
      @gender_ref = 'he/she'
    else if grammer == 'his'
      @gender_ref == 'his/her'
    else if grammer == 'him'
      @gender_ref == 'him/her'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a map

```
var rules = {
    'female': {
        'he': 'she',
        'his': 'her',
        // ...
    },
    'male': {
        'he': 'he',
        // ...
    },
    'default': {
        'he': 'he/she'
        // ...
    }
};

this.gender_ref = rules[gender ? gender : 'default'][grammer];
```

It's extensible and can also be dynamically generated from another backend (e.g. a DB).

*Edit (by Linus G Thiel)* The same in coffeescript:

```
rules =
  female:
    he: 'she'
    his: 'her'
    // ...
  male:
    he: 'he'
    // ...
  default:
    he: 'he/she'
    // ...

@gender_ref = rules[gender or 'default'][grammer]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use a switch-statement

```
switch (gender) {
  case "1":
    alert("");
    break;
  case "2":
    alert("");
    break;
  case "3":
    alert("");
    break;
  case "4":
    alert("");
    break;
  default:
    alert("default");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a multi-dimensional hash table.

```
grammarByGender = {
    "male": { "he" : "he", "his": "his", "him": "him" },
    "female": {"he" : "she", "his" :"her", "him":"her"},
    "neuter": {"he":"he/she","his":"his/her","him":"him/her"}
}

@gender_ref = grammarByGender[this.get("gender")][grammer]
```

Comment: Nice answer. I like the use of `"neuter"` :). It has a mix of CoffeeScript and JS syntax though. I'd recommend using Coffee's brace-less object literals to make the code a bit less crowded, and also add a conditional on the `grammarByGender[...]` access so `"neuter"` is used when there's no gender. [Example](http://goo.gl/bhT0C).

Comment: And [here's another example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:makeGrammar%20%3D%20%28he%2C%20his%2C%20him%29%20-%3E%20%7Bhe%2C%20his%2C%20him%7D%0A%0AgrammarByGender%20%3D%0A%20%20male%3A%20makeGrammar%20%22he%22%2C%20%22his%22%2C%20%22him%22%0A%20%20female%3A%20makeGrammar%20%22she%22%2C%20%22her%22%2C%20%22her%22%0A%20%20neuter%3A%20makeGrammar%20%22he%2Fshe%22%2C%20%22his%2Fher%22%2C%20%22him%2Fher%22%0A%0A%40gender_ref%20%3D%20grammarByGender[%40get%28%22gender%22%29%20%3F%20%22neuter%22][grammer]) that uses a little function to avoid some code repetition :)

Answer (score 2):

Use map to cache the possible values. You can extend it at any point and will be able to simplify your method:

```
var genders = {
    "male" : {
       "he": "he",
       "his": "his",
       "him": "him"
   },
   "female" : {
       "he": "she",
       "his": "her",
       "him": "her" 
   },
   "null": {
      "he": "he/she",
      "his": "his/her",
      "him": "him/her"
   }
}

function getGenderRef (grammer) {
  var gender_ref = "",
      availableGenders = genders[this.get('gender')];

  if (availableGenders) {
      gender_ref = availableGenders[grammer];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduse the length a tiny bit as follows:

```
getGenderRef: (grammer=nil) ->
  @gender_ref = ""
  gender = this.get('gender')
  if gender? and gender == 'male'
    if grammer == 'he'
      @gender_ref = 'he'
    else if grammer == 'his'
      @gender_ref == 'his'
    else if grammer == 'him'
      @gender_ref == 'him'
  else if gender? and gender == 'female'
    if grammer == 'he'
      @gender_ref = 'she'
    else if grammer == 'his' or grammer == 'him'
      @gender_ref == 'her'
  else if gender? or gender == null
    if grammer == 'he'
      @gender_ref = 'he/she'
    else if grammer == 'his'
      @gender_ref == 'his/her'
    else if grammer == 'him'
      @gender_ref == 'him/her'
```

You can't make it a lot shorter than this, because you have alot of different output options.
A swtich / case could be a option, but that would be just as much code.

Another option would be to use a object:

```
references = {
    'male': {
        'he': 'he',
        'his': 'his',
        'him': 'him'
    },
    'female': {
        'he': 'she',
        'his': 'her',
        'him': 'her'
    },
    'null':{
        'he': 'he/she',
        'his': 'his/her',
        'him': 'him/her'
    }
}
//Access:
gender_ref = references[gender ? gender : 'null'][gender_ref];
```

Comment: Isn't this what Felix just suggested? Btw default no longer works because you changed the key name to null.

Comment: I guess, but I saw that only after posting. Can't we use a `'null'` string as key?

Comment: Your map looks surprisingly equal to Felix's versions, same quotes, same order, same variable names...

Comment: @Christoph Maybe that is because I used the variables and order specified in the question.
I've had it happen before that 2 answers had the same code, simply because that's the way it should be done. Also, I always use single quotes: php habit.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy if you go step-by-step. You would learn how to refactor complex conditions that way.

First, notice that you have a common check in the first `if` and its subsequent `else if`s, that is `if gender?`. You should take that out as a common check and refactor your code as follows:

```
  if gender?
    ...
  else # if gender == null
    ...
```

This forms your main if and else clause. You will nest if and switch statements under these. The refactored if/else code is given below:

```
  if gender?
    if gender == 'male'
      switch grammer
        when 'he' then @gender_ref = 'he'
        when 'his' then @gender_ref = 'his'
        when 'him' then @gender_ref = 'him'
    else if gender == 'female'
      switch grammer
        when 'he' then @gender_ref = 'she'
        when 'his' then @gender_ref = 'her'
        when 'him' then @gender_ref = 'her'
  else # if gender == null
    switch grammer
      when 'he' then @gender_ref = 'he/she'
      when 'his' then @gender_ref = 'his/her'
      when 'him' then @gender_ref = 'him/her'
```

Switches in Coffeescript can work great for your situation, making the code pretty readable and less complex. You can optimize this further.

---

Here is a simple optimization, where you do the assignment to `@gender_ref` at the beginning of `switch` statement (again, taking the common part out):

```
  if gender?
    if gender == 'male'
      @gender_ref = switch grammer
        when 'he' then 'he'
        when 'his' then 'his'
        when 'him' then 'him'
    else if gender == 'female'
      @gender_ref = switch grammer
        when 'he' then 'she'
        when 'his' then 'her'
        when 'him' then 'her'
  else # if gender == null
    @gender_ref = switch grammer
      when 'he' then 'he/she'
      when 'his' then 'his/her'
      when 'him' then 'him/her'
```

You can optimize it even further by moving `@gender_ref =` assignment to the parent if (it's not working in the else clause though ... I wonder why).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance there is nothing wrong with if statements. I can't help but wonder if this isn't just about readibility.

Anyway here is another option still using if statements.

```
@gender_ref = grammer; // male values are the same so use as default

if(  gender == "female" ) {

    if( grammer == 'he' ) @gender_ref = 'she';
    if( grammer == 'his' ) @gender_ref = 'her';
    if( grammer == 'him' ) @gender_ref = 'her';

} else if (  !gender ) { // if not defined

    if( grammer == 'he' ) @gender_ref = 'he/she';
    if( grammer == 'his' ) @gender_ref = 'his/her';
    if( grammer == 'him' ) @gender_ref = 'him/her';
}
```

Comment: by replacing the `else if` with `if` you are changing the behaviour of the code...

Comment: missing for the nested `if` too...;)

Comment: Although the behaviour is different the output is the same.

Comment: that's true but nonetheless this is dangerous because you cant ensure that there is no case where the output infact WILL differ due to the different behaviour. Thus one should never alter the code without even telling the OP. Maybe he won't notice and run into trouble later - who knows?